# How to show multiple charts on Django use python-highcharts?

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts, highcharts

How to show multiple charts on Django use python-highcharts ?
When I Show multiple charts, it shows

> Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #16: [www.highcharts.com/errors/16](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16)

and other charts always show Loading...
Only one chart can show .

Error details:

> "Highcharts already defined in the page. This error happens the second
> time, Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page, so the
> Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in mind that the
> Highcharts ,Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are
> included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and StockChart in
> combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file"

Comment: It would help if you show how you are trying to achieve it in django, however, the url in your error message: https://www.highcharts.com/errors/16, tells me that somehow you are including the highcharts library twice in you HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I have solved this problem.

Because of the default div id is "container", add renderTo new div id ,then can work !

Thank you

```
options = {
        'chart': {
            'renderTo': 'div id'
                 }
          }
```